# Event Listeners on Dynamic Buttons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, model-view-controller, jbutton

I've been struggling with this for a while, I'm trying to build a program that makes use of the MVC pattern, that dynamically creates a grid of buttons (nxn) based on user input. I can't however get it right to attach listeners to them.

EDIT: I meant that I wanted to handle the event inside of the Controller class to conform to the MVC pattern

View

```
public class AIGameView extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private AIGameModel model;
private JButton[][] btn_arr;

public AIGameView(AIGameModel m) {
    model = m;
    initComponents();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {...}                                 

private void startBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    options.setVisible(false);
    int size = Integer.parseInt(size_field.getText());
    model.setSize(size);
    btn_arr = new JButton[size][size];
    GameGUI.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(size, size));
    for(int y = 0; y < size; y++)  {
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)  {
            btn_arr[y][x] = new JButton();
            btn_arr[y][x].setBackground(Color.white);
            GameGUI.add(btn_arr[y][x]);
            btn_arr[y][x].setVisible(true);

        }
    }
    GameGUI.setVisible(true);
    GameGUI.revalidate();
    GameGUI.repaint();
}
```

Controller

```
public class AIGameController {

private AIGameView view;
private AIGameModel model;
private JButton[][] buttons;

public AIGameController(AIGameModel m, AIGameView v)    {
    view = v;
    model = m;
}
```

I've tried several things, but nothing seems to work for this and I mostly just end up with a null pointer exception. Any advice on this ?

Comment: Are you successfully getting into the method startBtnActionPerformed() ?

Comment: Yes, it creates the grid. Sorry took some of the code out as I'm using Netbeans to create the GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code that you posted so far, it seems that you could add a call

```
btn_arr[y][x] = new JButton();
btn_arr[y][x].addActionListener(createActionListener(y, x));
...
```

With a method like

```
private ActionListener createActionListener(final int y, final int x)
{
    return new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("Clicked "+y+" "+x);

            // Some method that should be called in 
            // response to the button click:
            clickedButton(y,x);
        }
    };
}

private void clickedButton(int y, int x)
{
    // Do whatever has to be done now...
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this go against the MVC pattern ?

Comment: @ChrisCrossman There *has* to be some `ActionListener` attached to the button. And this is the "minimal" way of attaching an `ActionListener` to the button and still retaining the information about which button was clicked. To put it that way: It's up to you to only call `controller.doSomethingWith(x,y)` in the `clickedButton` method. Or is your question aiming at injecting the ActionListeners from the outside? MVC is slightly controversial in this point (What is a controller, anyway?). For me, each `ActionListener` already *is* a little controller. Let's see what others say.

Comment: I was trying to get something in the lines of: http://leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html but with that I end up with a nullpointer as the buttons aren't created yet. But I understand what you mean by that. I might just add a reference to the controller in the view if I can't find another solution.

Comment: Agree with Marco. If you want your view interactions to provide some logic you're going to have to pass your controller into the view. Once your actionPerformed is called, you can call a method in the controller to perform the logic.

Comment: @Zyn I decided to just pass a reference to the View as Zyn also said, It does simplify it quite a lot. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you're going through your initialisation loop :

```
for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)  {
  btn_arr[y][x] = new JButton();
  btn_arr[y][x].setBackground(Color.white);
  GameGUI.add(btn_arr[y][x]);
  btn_arr[y][x].setVisible(true);
  btn_arr[y][x].addActionListener( new YourListener() );
}
```